# why json array value is converted to string when using in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

My json is

```
{
    "data": {
        "cols": ["1102", "1103", "1104", "1105", "1106", "1107", "1108", "1109"],
        "form_id": "39",
        "ph_id": "137",
        "rows1": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
        "rows2": ["147", "148", "149", "150", "151"],
        "user_id": "4",
        "util_id": "1",
        "val": {
            "misc_vals": [
                ["Transmission Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Distribution Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Metering Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Other Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Less: Contribution from consumbers including advance from them", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"]
            ],
            "station_vals": [
                ["KOLAGHAT THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["BANDEL THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["BAKRESHWAR THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["SANTALDIH THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["SAGARDIGHI THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["HYDEL POWER STATION"],
                ["Total", "=SUM(A1:A6)", "=SUM(B1:B6)", "=SUM(C1:C6)", "=SUM(D1:D6)", "=SUM(E1:E6)", "=SUM(F1:F6)", "=SUM(G1:G6)", "=SUM(H1:H6)"]
            ]
        }
    },
    "message": "Form 1.18_1 matrix fetched Successfully",
    "status": 1
}
```

when I am consoling it the value inside the val->misc_val and station_vals->comma separeted values are showing as string.

I am using angular js and i need the comma separated value inside the array of misc_val and station_vals as array.

I used parse for that but i got an error

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 1"

in console.

It will be glad if you please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you wrap you JSON inside `' '` . I wraped and it is ok.

Comment: Those are arrays of strings.... they are quoted numbers therefore they are strings when parsed with JSON.parse if you can please clarify with what you are attempting to do in the end here (are you expecting numbers somewhere but getting strings? specifically where? to turn a string to a number in JS use parseFloat or parseInt

Comment: I checked it on Plunker and your Json data is perfectly fine so I guess there is some silly mistake in code or parsing data, please check or share your complete code piece.

Comment: you can give it a try by escape (\\) quotes or other character if you feel it can cause error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var JSONData = `{
    "data": {
        "cols": ["1102", "1103", "1104", "1105", "1106", "1107", "1108", "1109"],
        "form_id": "39",
        "ph_id": "137",
        "rows1": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
        "rows2": ["147", "148", "149", "150", "151"],
        "user_id": "4",
        "util_id": "1",
        "val": {
            "misc_vals": [
                ["Transmission Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Distribution Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Metering Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Other Assets", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["Less: Contribution from consumbers including advance from them", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"]
            ],
            "station_vals": [
                ["KOLAGHAT THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["BANDEL THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["BAKRESHWAR THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["SANTALDIH THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["SAGARDIGHI THERMAL POWER STATION", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000", "0.000"],
                ["HYDEL POWER STATION"],
                ["Total", "=SUM(A1:A6)", "=SUM(B1:B6)", "=SUM(C1:C6)", "=SUM(D1:D6)", "=SUM(E1:E6)", "=SUM(F1:F6)", "=SUM(G1:G6)", "=SUM(H1:H6)"]
            ]
        }
    },
    "message": "Form 1.18_1 matrix fetched Successfully",
    "status": 1
}`

const parsedData = JSON.parse(JSONData)
console.log(parsedData);

console.log('STATUS IS ', parsedData.status, typeof parsedData.status)
console.log('MISC_VALS IS Array?', parsedData.data.val.misc_vals instanceof Array)
console.log('MISC_VALS ELEMENT IS?', typeof parsedData.data.val.misc_vals[0][3], parsedData.data.val.misc_vals[0][3])
```

Note I used backticks in the code above and allowed it to be run through babel to avoid having to hack together the string in JS or condense it to one line or something else hackish.  This shows that it parses fine though and it also shows the types of the objects after parsing, if you want to convert the elemnets in the arrays to numbers they need to come without quotes around them or they need to be run through parseFloat or parseInt as appropriate.